# chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab vs chrome.desktopCapture

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm new to Chrome extension development and I am trying to build an extension which take's screenshot of the pages of an ebook. 
So I was reading the chrome extension documentation and came across both of these APIs which has pretty much the same description. So if any one of you can help out with the difference, similarities or use cases for both of these.

Comment: captureVisibleTab returns a data URL, desktopCapture shows an additional UI and returns a media stream.

Comment: @wOxxOm  So I guess, captureVisibleTab will be best for my case